# label_visualization:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ndim'

Tags: visualization

[my question is that i am using binary classification using unet after geting my result i need to label my result with different colours when i apply i run this code it give me this error .any body have any idea about this issue.
Thanks in advance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGQUm.png)

my question is that i am using binary classification using unet after geting my result i need to label my result with different colours when i apply i run this code it give me this error .any body have any idea about this issue.
Thanks in advance